# How to rearrange this csv email name list

Tags: csv, email

I have a .csv list of emails + names.
Each name can have 1-3 emails along with it (which are currently separated by a comma).
I need to convert this into a .csv list where its 1 name and 1 email.

Here is example:

```
John Smith,johnsmith1@gmail.com,johnsmith2@gmail.com,johnsmith3@gmail.com
Taylor Smith,taylorsmith@gmail.com
Jack Smith,jacksmith1@gmail.com,jacksmith@gmail.com
...(and there are like 10k more rows)
```

How can I automatically convert this to:

```
John Smith,johnsmith1@gmail.com
John Smith,johnsmith2@gmail.com
John Smith,johnsmith3@gmail.com
Taylor Smith,taylorsmith@gmail.com
Jack Smith,jacksmith1@gmail.com
Jack Smith,jacksmith@gmail.com
```

The main problem here attaching the name to separate rows of the emails that were intially with that name.

I appreciate any help - seems like an easy task, but was stuck on this for few days already, Thanks.

Comment: Can this be solved in Notepad++ or what tool are you using? Is a two step replace ok?

Comment: Does this need to be fully automated, or are manual steps ok?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) here is a two steps solution:

Replace > Options: Check • Regular expressions, Uncheck [ ] `.` matches newline

1. Rearrange line -> Move Name to end of the line
   Search for `^([^,@\n]+),(.+)\R?` and replace with `$2,$1\n`
   **Step 1** > [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T32nif/1) (explanation on the right side)
2. Now the Name can be [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) inside a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and used as a [replacement](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html).
   Search for `([^\n,]++)(?=.*,([^\n,@]+$)),(?:(?1)(?:\n|$))?` and replace with `$2,$1\n`
   **Step 2** > [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hlUMQf/2)

   Each comma seperated substring gets captured by the *first group* while the *second group* captures the Name inside a lookahead and is put before the E-Mail and removed from the end.

After both steps the result should look like your desired outcome. *Further info*: [SO Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985)

Comment: Broooooooo thats so dope!
It works ++
I almost j***zed my pants from the satisfaction of how smooth this code is,

Thx for this reply bro +++

Comment:  @markothehacker Hehe glad that works for you! (you don't need to write answer "another answer works" you can just click on the checkmark to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved it)